# playing sound x times, x seconds apart. setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript

when a condition is met I want to play a notification sound (short beep) an x amount of times with an x amount of time in between. I wrote the following script:

```
function repeat(times) {
  document.getElementById("alert").play();
  if (--times > 0){
    setTimeout(repeat(times), 3000);
    // also tried this, but didnt work either
    // setTimeout(document.getElementById("alert").play, 3000);
  }
}
repeat(3)
```

when checking in safari debugger there are no errors and setTimeout gets triggered, but after the first beep, no other sound is heard. (length of audio file is aprox 1 sec)

can someone explain why its not working?

Comment: Replace `setTimeout(repeat(times), 3000);` with `setTimeout(function () { repeat(times); }, 3000);` (you need to wrap the call in an anonymous function, otherwise the call is executed immediately, then the return value (`null`) is scheduled to run)

Comment: You are calling `repeat(times)` and assigning what it returns to the setTimeout. You are not binding the call.

Comment: ofcourse! thanks @ChrisG that fixed it. could you also explain why setTimeout(document.getElementById("alert").play, 3000) isn't working?

Comment: @Diego Apparently that'll only work if the element is already an `HTMLMediaElement`.

Comment: @ChrisG <audio> is a media element right? this is the html code: <audio id="alert" preload="auto" src="alert.wav"></audio>

Comment: Yes, but `document.getElementById` returns an `HTMLElement`. Those don't have a `play()` function. Not sure that you can construct an element that already has the `HTMLMediaElement` interface from the start.

Comment: Not sure I understand, because document.getElementById("alert").play(); works, but this doesnt setTimeout(document.getElementById("alert").play, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

Try to use short sounds, because if you play the sound before the previous sound finished, the second sound will be muted.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<audio id="sound">
  <source src="alert.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
<input type="text" id="times" value="5">
<button id="btn" type="button">Play Alert</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var audio = new Audio("alert.wav");
        let times = 0;
        $("#btn").on("click", function() {
            times = parseInt(document.getElementById("times").value);
            playAudio();
        });

        playAudio = function() {
            audio.play()
            times --;
            if (times) setTimeout(playAudio, 333);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: that was not the problem, i already said the sound length was 1 sec, and you can see setInterval time is set to 3 sec. the correct answer is given by @chrisg

Comment: absolutely, my sample is working but not explain why your code fail. +1 to @chrisg